# Finding one coin of N in q steps

Tags: math, logic, mathematical-optimization, pseudocode

**Subject**: Finding One Coin of 13 in 3 Steps

There is a pile of thirteen coins, all of equal size. Twelve are of
equal weight.  One is of a different weight.  In three weighings(using scales) find
the unequal coin and determine if it is heavier or lighter.

I scratched my head on this one. I have found an answer but about 12.
Is it possible to do for 13 ?

So if it is possible can we end up with a method that can calculate the number of steps that are needed to find the unequal coin in pile of N. Pseudocode  is just fair enough.

NOTE: Do not forget we do not know if the coin is lighter or heavier.

PS: Solution for 12 and some interesting thoughts [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171229130337/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55618.html).

Comment: Could you add the solution for the 12-coins problem? Do you know that there exists a solution for the 13-coins problem with three steps?

Comment: No I have benn trying to figure it out mysleft. Still I have not dived into too deep search and long math articales.

Comment: Do you have a scale that gives you the actual weight or just some scale that lets you compare two weights? Your question seems to suggest the former, but the link suggests the latter.

Comment: Well only a scale that lets me compare two weights only. There is no measuring weights scale.

Answer (score 1):

No, we cannot find a method that is guaranteed to determine which coin is not equal to the others and if it is heavier or lighter then the others, not with the restrictions you lay out.

One weighing of coins has three possible results: left pan down and right pan up (so the total of weights on the left is greater than the total of weights on the right), left pan up and right pan down (so the total of weights on the left is less than the total of weights on the right), or the pans balance (so the total of weights on the left is equal to the total of weights on the right). If we want to distinguish between four or more possibilities with just one weighing, we may fail since we can guarantee only three. Similarly, two weighings can distinguish between at most nine possibilities, and three weighings can handle at most 27 possibilities. The problem has 13 coins, each of which may be light or heavy, so there are 26 possibilities to begin. It looks like we may be able to handle them.

However, the problem comes at the first weighing. What happens if we place four or fewer weights on each pan? If one side goes up, all we know is that the special coin is among the five or more coins we did not use. However, that is 10 possibilities: light or heavy, for five coins. Therefore two more weighings is not guaranteed to distinguish between them.

Now, what happens if we place five or more weights on each pan for the first weighing? If the left pan rises, either one of the five or more weights on the left is light or one of the five or more weights on the right is heavy. That is at least 10 possibilities, so two more weighings is not guaranteed to distinguish between them.

Either way we may end up with 10 or more possibilities to solve in two weighings, which spoils any solution. Any method that has only three possible results at each step will need to be more sophisticated than the weighing pans.